# What C++11 extensions does Clang support in C++03 mode?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

Newer versions of Clang support certain C++11 extensions when compiling in C++03 mode, but may issue a warning with `-Wc++11-extensions` turned on. For example, compiling this code:

```
std::map<int, int> foo;
for(auto &i : foo) {
}
```

with `clang test.cpp -std=c++03` results in these warnings:

```
test.cpp:5:6: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
        for(auto &i : foo) {
            ^
test.cpp:5:14: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
        for(auto &i : foo) {
```

but the compile succeeds and correct code is generated. However, trying to use e.g. uniform initialization (`std::map<int, int> foo{{1,2},{3,4}};`) fails with a syntax error.

In my case, I have an existing, immutable library that only compiles in C++03 mode due to some compatibility issues; the developers have stated they will support C++11 in the 'near future'. I want to write code against this library using C++11 features now, so that I don't have to go back and "modernize" the code again when they make their library C++11-compatible. Clang's C++11 extensions seem ideal for this purpose, but I'm not sure what I can use. Are Clang's C++11 extensions documented somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two "feature-test" macros which you can put to use here:

`__has_feature` and `__has_extension`

These function-like macros take a single identifier argument that is the name of a feature. `__has_feature` evaluates to 1 if the feature is both supported by Clang and standardized in the current language standard or 0 if not, while `__has_extension` evaluates to 1 if the feature is supported by Clang in the current language (either as a language extension or a standard language feature) or 0 if not.

These macros, and the identifiers are documented here:

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html

In your specific example, the following HelloWorld is most informative:

```
#if __has_extension(cxx_generalized_initializers)
#warning __has_extension(cxx_generalized_initializers) is true
#else
#warning __has_extension(cxx_generalized_initializers) is false
#endif

#if __has_feature(cxx_generalized_initializers)
#warning __has_feature(cxx_generalized_initializers) is true
#else
#warning __has_feature(cxx_generalized_initializers) is false
#endif

#if __has_extension(cxx_range_for)
#warning __has_extension(cxx_range_for) is true
#else
#warning __has_extension(cxx_range_for) is false
#endif

#if __has_feature(cxx_range_for)
#warning __has_feature(cxx_range_for) is true
#else
#warning __has_feature(cxx_range_for) is false
#endif

int main()
{
}
```

For me, with -std=c++03 it outputs:

```
test.cpp:4:2: warning: __has_extension(cxx_generalized_initializers) is false [-W#warnings]
#warning __has_extension(cxx_generalized_initializers) is false
 ^
test.cpp:10:2: warning: __has_feature(cxx_generalized_initializers) is false [-W#warnings]
#warning __has_feature(cxx_generalized_initializers) is false
 ^
test.cpp:14:2: warning: __has_extension(cxx_range_for) is true [-W#warnings]
#warning __has_extension(cxx_range_for) is true
 ^
test.cpp:22:2: warning: __has_feature(cxx_range_for) is false [-W#warnings]
#warning __has_feature(cxx_range_for) is false
 ^
4 warnings generated.
```

Whereas with -std=c++11 the output changes to:

```
test.cpp:2:2: warning: __has_extension(cxx_generalized_initializers) is true [-W#warnings]
#warning __has_extension(cxx_generalized_initializers) is true
 ^
test.cpp:8:2: warning: __has_feature(cxx_generalized_initializers) is true [-W#warnings]
#warning __has_feature(cxx_generalized_initializers) is true
 ^
test.cpp:14:2: warning: __has_extension(cxx_range_for) is true [-W#warnings]
#warning __has_extension(cxx_range_for) is true
 ^
test.cpp:20:2: warning: __has_feature(cxx_range_for) is true [-W#warnings]
#warning __has_feature(cxx_range_for) is true
 ^
4 warnings generated.
```

For your use case, you could lace your code with `__has_extension(cxx_generalized_initializers)` and use the new feature when true, else work around it when false.  Your code will then automatically adapt as you upgrade your clang, or as the language mode used changes.

As for what language feature is supported and which isn't, the documentation may help, but I find writing a test such as that above is the fastest and most accurate way to assess my current clang version.

Comment: Nice! I wrote a little program to list all the features. As of Clang 4.2, it seems that *deleted functions, inline namespaces, local type template args, override control keywords, reference qualified functions, range for* and *rvalue references* are supported.

Comment: What's odd is that `__has_extension(cxx_auto_type)` is false, yet (as you can see in my example) `auto &i` compiles just fine.

Comment: @nneonneo: It seems that in Clang 3.3 (devel. version), all the tests compile to 'true', except for `cxx_inheriting_constructors`. And according to [their table](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html), it seems `thread_local` will also be missing in the next release. But it's getting close. I would imagine that they don't make the `__has_extension` evaluate to true until the support is definitive and stable, that's why `cxx_auto_type` might evaluate to false while the code works.

Comment: @MikaelPersson We don't make `__has_extension(cxx_auto_type)` evaluate to true in C++98 mode because there are some corner cases in C++98 mode where we would reject correct uses of the `auto` type (because we treat it as an `auto` storage class specifier instead).